# html background image in existing html code?

Tags: php, html, css

So, I need to put a background repeating image in the background of a php file with html code in it. I have tried to put the background image in many times but it either doesn't work or messes with the already in place code. If anyone could help me figure out how to put the background image in the file and explain how it can be done, it would be very nice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="styles/defaultstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<title>Professional Development and Training || Lewis-Clark State College</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


</head>
<body>




<div id="container">
<div id="banner">
<!-- this is a PROBLEM you shouldn't have two heads, the CSS needs to be moved over-->
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: x-large;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.auto-style2 {
text-align: center;
}

</style>
</head>


<!--Start of the header, and LCSC logo image -->
<div class="auto-style2">
<a href="http://connect.lcsc.edu/pdt">
<img alt="LCSC Blue Flag Logo" height="63" src="images/LCSCLogo-small.jpg" width="194">
</a>

<span class="auto-style1">
<strong><br>Professional Development &amp; Training (PDT)</strong>
</span>
</div>

<!-- strip just below banner -->
<h1>training success daily</h1>
</div>


<div id="wrapper">
<div>
<?php
$connStr = 'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' .
                    'Dbq=G:\Users\Warhammer\Documents\Databases_and_Knowledge\courses_php-master\course.mdb;';
try {
$handler = new PDO($connStr);
$handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
die();
}

$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM tblCourses WHERE startDate > #1/1/2017#');
?>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Course Title</th>
<th>Points</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Instructor</th>
<th>Location</th> 
</tr>

<?php
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $r['subject']; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $r['points']; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $r['startDate']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $r['startTime']; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $r['category']; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $r['instructor']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $r['location']; ?></td>
</tr>


<?php
}
?>
</table>
</div>

<br /><br />
</div>
<div id="footer"><h1>Lewis-Clark State College  ||  Professional Development and Training  ||  For more information please contact: jcrea@lcsc.edu</h1></div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the image I want to repeat in the background

[image: This is the image I want to repeat in the background]

Comment: for a start learn valid html . this is nothing to do with php

Comment: I don't see any background definition!, post your CSS file and also as suggested under your html move content of your 2nd head tag to the first head tag and remove 2n head tag this is not a valid HTML

Comment: Wouldn't you just use CSS? `body { background: url(your-image.png) repeat; }`

Comment: Will you write yourself:- `<!-- this is a PROBLEM you shouldn't have two heads, the CSS needs to be moved over-->`  then why don't you did that?

Comment: i suspect that's feed back from the teacher.

Comment: That part was in the code before i got it, the html we are recycling from the old website, im just supposed to add a repeating background to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the corrected code to be in first head. css is to add repeating background image. Remove the second head

```
   <style type="text/css">
                    .auto-style1 {
                        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                        font-size: x-large;
                        color: #FFFFFF;
                    }
                    .auto-style2 {
                        text-align: center;
                    }
    body{

    background: url(b.jpg) repeat;

    }


                  </style>
```